# Doublet-triplet splitting : Meaning of some mechanism names

Tags: supersymmetry, grand-unification

In order to solve the [Doublet–triplet splitting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet%E2%80%93triplet_splitting_problem), people have developped several mechanisms, such as the Missing Partner, the Missing VEV and the Sliding Singlet mechanism.

I couldn't really find any explanation for those names. What are their origins and how do they relate to the mechanism in itself?